# Simple Mail Transfer Protocal Script Error

Tags: python, smtp

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joshk/Desktop/LearningQt/LearnQt.py", line 14, in <module>
    server.login('joshuackeely@hotmail.com', password)
  File "C:\Users\joshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 700, in login
    raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Says "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server." Not sure if that means that @hotmail is supported or not, but I looked it up and I put:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 25)
```

and it said it was supported online, I thought.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: the error says pretty specifically what the problem is - what's the question here? Also, practically **no** reputable SMTP service allows for auth in any form over unencrypted connections. (luckily, this is 2021, not 1996.)

Comment: Yeah, I was just following a tutorial and it seemed to work just fine on their side. I'm pretty new to python so I'm not exactly sure what "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server." means...

Comment: this is not a python problem. You need to understand how SMTP works.

Comment: That's fair. I failed my A+ at a 70%, so I know I could learn a thing or two about that haha. Care to explain?

Comment: no, this is all well-documented in links you find on the wikipedia when researching SMTP authentication :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the connection before the login:

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 25)
server.connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 25)
```

And you probably want to use TLS instead, most providers only support connections with it.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should've used that. However, I'm following a tutorial and it worked just fine for the dude on there, even on port 25.

Comment: That must be an ages old tutorial then. Any serious providers will simply not allow you to send your login over unencrypted channels.

Comment: well the tutorial was on Aug 19th, 2020...feels like ages ago